# Canadian postal code validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate a Canadian postal code (for example, `M4B 1C7`) using C# (.NET) regular expressions.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Canadian postal codes can't contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U, and cannot start with W or Z:

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

If you want an optional space in the middle:

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Comment: +1 for "Canadian postal codes can't have certain letters".  You might want to also add that the leading letter is more restricted, then the second and third.

Comment: thanks a ton for answer...this works fine for codes like M4B1E8 ...but it wont work for M4B 1E8. Canada postal could have space after 3 characters..reference here:http://www.mongabay.com/igapo/toronto_zip_codes.htm

Comment: Ideally, you should ignore whitespace on input and normalise the data to a canonical format for storage. That way, people can enter postal codes with or without spaces, and it won't matter. You can format them for output purposes if needed.

Comment: There shouldn't be an F in the first sequence, you can check here: http://www.infinitegravity.ca/postalcodeformat.htm to verify

Comment: If you want the space to be optional, put a question mark after it.

Comment: The letter 'F' is not used in Canadian postal codes. Also, your second regexp contains an extra 'U' at the end (typo!)

Comment: Note, these regexs do not take in account of trailing or leading characters; nor, will it check length. If this important to you, you should prepend "^" and append "$" to the regexs in order to the assert that from the starting to the ending of the string to be match is a valid postal code. Example: `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$`

Comment: ^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$

Answer (score 5):

Here are the rules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code#Reserved_characters

```
ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY <-- letter used 
DFIOQU <-- letters not used because it mixes up the reader
WZ     <-- letters used but not in the first letter
With that in mind the following in the proper regex

@[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][\s][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

```
bool FoundMatch = false;
try {
    FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, "\\A[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z] ?\\d[A-Z]\\d\\z");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: I've modified my answer to exclude invalid letters in the first character, as per http://www.infinitegravity.ca/postalcodeformat.htm.

Comment: f you don't want to have to do two slashes for every slash, use an @ string literal as in `@"\A[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d\z"`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function postalCodeCheck (postalCode, type) {

    if (!postalCode) {
        return null;
    }

    postalCode = postalCode.toString().trim();

    var us = new RegExp("^\\d{5}(-{0,1}\\d{4})?$");
   // var ca  = new RegExp(/^((?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z])|(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z]\ ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/i);
    var ca = new RegExp(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]( )?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i);

    if(type == "us"){
        if (us.test(postalCode.toString())) {
            console.log(postalCode);
            return postalCode;
        }
    }

    if(type == "ca")
    {
        if (ca.test(postalCode.toString())) {
            console.log(postalCode);
            return postalCode;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not C#. The OP asked about c#

Answer (score -1):

Validating the format of a postal code without validating its meaning isn't worth it, since typos can still result in a valid postal code for the wrong address.  You want to validate the code against the address database.  See http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/atoz/postalcodeproducts.jsf

Comment: the canada post link is dead

Comment: https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/ is a link to the start of the can post validation feature. Great tool, free trial.

Answer (score -4):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string c1;
        string c2;
        string c3;
        string c4;
        string c5;
        string c6;
        string c7;
        int sortie;
        bool parfais = true;


        Console.WriteLine("entrer votre code postal");
        string cp = Console.ReadLine();
        if (cp.Length == 7)
        {

            c1 = cp.Substring(0, 1);
            c2 = cp.Substring(1, 1);
            c3 = cp.Substring(2, 1);
            c4 = cp.Substring(3, 1);
            c5 = cp.Substring(4, 1);
            c6 = cp.Substring(5, 1);
            c7 = cp.Substring(6, 1);



            if (int.TryParse(c1, out sortie))
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 1er caratere doit etre une lettre");
            }

            if (int.TryParse(c2, out sortie) == false)
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 2e caratere doit etre un nombre");
            }

            if (int.TryParse(c3, out sortie))
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 3e caratere doit etre une lettre");
            }



            if (c4.Contains(" ") == false)
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("vous devez utiliser un espace");
            }



            if (int.TryParse(c5, out sortie) == false)
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 5e caratere doit etre un nombre");
            }

            if (int.TryParse(c6, out sortie))
            {
                parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 6e caratere doit etre une lettre");
            }

            if (int.TryParse(c7, out sortie) == false)
            {
                 parfais = false;
                Console.WriteLine("le 7e caratere doit etre un nombre");
            }

            else if(parfais == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("code postal accepter");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


       }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("le code postal doit contenir 7 caratere incluant l'espace");

            }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The OP wants to use regular expressions. There aren't any in this answer.