# javascript regex for canadian postal code

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Canada postal code validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146202/canada-postal-code-validation)

I need javascript regex for validating Canadian postal/zip code.
Canada's Postal Code format is '`A1A 1X1' or 'a1a1x1'`. However it doesn't include the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U.I found few here but those were in C#.

Comment: var tmp = new RegExp(/^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] +?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/i) 

ref: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596802837/id2991897 added: multiple spaces in-between are optional, case-insensitive

Comment: Worth noting that a good question should show some effort on your part. ;-)

Comment: @Tass see my answer below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function checkPostal(postal) {
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]( )?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i);
    if (regex.test(postal.value))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Might want to strip spaces to the left/right (or even in the middle).

Comment: Space in the middle is facultative so it does well the job. Just adjust the return values to true (first) and false (last). Then, be aware that this function tests regex on variable 'postal' 'value'. I reedited the third line as follows :
        if (regex.test(postal))
...providing the value to the function directly.

Comment: Be aware that the no usage of certain characters may change in time as new postal code would be needed.

Answer (score -2):

As the exceptional words have nothing in common, the valid words should be written one by one.

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]
```

Followed by a digit

```
\d
```

And this three times

```
{3}
```

Finally we add "i" for case-insensitive

```
var regex = /([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d){3}/i;
```

Comment: The first digit can't be Z, for example.