# Restrictive RegEx for validate Canada postal code

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a Canada Postal Code and I saw several RegEx [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773523/javascript-regex-for-canadian-postal-code), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146202/canadian-postal-code-validation) and many more but none of them works as should be. I am trying with this one:

```
/[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]/gmi
```

Which is not working good as you may see in [this test](https://regex101.com/r/vB9gT5/1)  there should only match the first line because postal code needs **and it's mandatory** `3AllowedChars_emptySpace_3AllowedChars`, then having this, how do I restrict only 3 chars before the empty space and 3 after and of course having the valid chars for Canada postal code? Any help?

**UPDATE**

Based on the solution posted here is the fix:

```
/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Za-z][ -]\d[A-Za-z]\d$/gmi
```

The problem is that **?** before `[ -]` means optional and the empty space is not optional. You can test valid matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/vB9gT5/4)

Comment: Use anchors `^` and `$` (see e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is a regex for canada postal code, try this:

```
^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d$
```

It should do exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Almost there, if you try the same string without empty spaces on the middle you will get a match, I tried to fix this but couldn't

Comment: See [here](https://regex101.com/r/vB9gT5/2): `K1G6C9` shouldn't be matched and it's matching

Comment: if you remove the `?` after `[ -]` it will force it to have either a space or dash