# Canadian postal code regex?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

In the postal code field only the following format should be valid.

B1C 2B3 or B1C3D3

how to write a regex for this?

Edited:

```
^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$
```

This is my regex but it only accepting B1C C1B (notice space in between )  format. even with out space should be valid

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is C# not VB.NET but I expect it translates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146202/canada-postal-code-validation

Comment: If these are the only three values that you expect, what's wrong with `B1C|C1B|B1CC1B` regex?

Comment: @SLaks :  "^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$" this is my regex but it only accepting B1C C1B (notice space in between )  format. even with out space should be valid

Comment: I don't think you want the brackets around the space.

Comment: Those aren't valid Canadian postal codes. The format is `A0A 0A0`, where `A` stands for a letter and `0` stands for a digit.

Comment: @VadimK his regexp is right, though, just not his examples

Answer (score 4):

There are some real inconsistencies here. The Regex you provided `^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$` matches what was stated by Scott regarding the correct Canadian format. However, the examples you provided do not follow the format `B1C C1B or B1CC1B`.

To add insult to injury, the Regex you provided works with the proper Canadian format. So there isn't any real reason to change it. I mean, I would change it to this `^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$` so that the single space isn't grouped, but that's just me.

However, as far as using it, it could be used in C# like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Match(inputString, @"^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$");
if (!matches.Success) {
    // do something because it didn't match
}
```

and now that it's been tagged with VB.NET:

```
Dim matches = Regex.Match(inputString, "^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$")
If Not matches.Success Then
    ' do something because it didn't match
End If
```

Comment: Actually the regex is `[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]` AAA AAA is not a valid Canadian zip code. neither is `B1C\t0A2` (the op's orignal example was wrong too)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, my apologies, I'll take the OP's current Regex and fix it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I fixed it, but there are some real inconsistencies in the OP's question.

Comment: This could be shortened with a case insensitive flag and then `a-zA-Z` could be `A-Z`

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to validate the postal code against [the address database](http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/atoz/postalcodeproducts.jsf). Not every postal code in the format `A0A0A0` is a valid Canadian postal code. Examples of postal codes that do not exist:

```
Z0Z0Z0
Z9Z9Z9
Y7Y7Y7
```

Regarding preliminary checking, the easiest would probably be one with pre-processing of the value by VB.NET code. You need to remove spaces and convert to upper case. Then your regex is very simple: `([A-Z]\d){3}`. And here is the full code for testing:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(CanBeValidCanadianPostalCode("B1C 2B3")) 'prints True
    Console.WriteLine(CanBeValidCanadianPostalCode("B1C3D3")) 'prints True
  End Sub

  Private Function CanBeValidCanadianPostalCode(postal_code As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(postal_code.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper, "([A-Z]\d){3}")
  End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex for Canadian ZIP code validations

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$
```

Comment: This is the proper answer.